# GCP - BigTable to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to query Bigtable data in BigQuery using the external table configuration. I have the following SQL command that I am working with. However, I get an error stating `invalid bigtable_options for format CLOUD_BIGTABLE.`
The code works when I remove the `columns` field. For context, the raw data looks like this (running query without column field):

| rowkey | aAA.column.name | aAA.column.cell.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4271 | xxx | 30 |
|  | yyy | 25 |

But I would like the table to look like this:

| rowkey | xxx |
| --- | --- |
| 4271 | 30 |

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev_test.telem_test
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CLOUD_BIGTABLE',
  uris = ['https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/telem/instances/dbb-bigtable/tables/db1'],
  bigtable_options =  
    """
    {
      bigtableColumnFamilies: [
        {
          "familyId": "aAA",
          "type": "string",
          "encoding": "string",
          "columns": [
            {
              "qualifierEncoded": string,
              "qualifierString": string,
              "fieldName": "xxx",
              "type": string,
              "encoding": string,
              "onlyReadLatest": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      readRowkeyAsString: true
    }
    """
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you let the default value for each column attribute. the `string` is the type of the value to provide, but not the raw value to provide. It makes no sense in JSON here. Try to add double quote like that

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev_test.telem_test
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CLOUD_BIGTABLE',
  uris = ['https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/telem/instances/dbb-bigtable/tables/db1'],
  bigtable_options =  
    """
    {
      bigtableColumnFamilies: [
        {
          "familyId": "aAA",
          "type": "string",
          "encoding": "string",
          "columns": [
            {
              "qualifierEncoded": "string",
              "qualifierString": "string",
              "fieldName": "xxx",
              "type": "string",
              "encoding": "string",
              "onlyReadLatest": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      readRowkeyAsString: true
    }
    """
    );
```

The false is correct because the type is a boolean. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#BigtableColumn). The encoding "string" will be erroneous (use a real encoding type).

Answer (score 1):

The error here is in this part:

```json
bigtableColumnFamilies: [
```

It should be:

```
  "columnFamilies": [
```

Concerning adding columns for string you will only add:

```
     "columns": [{
              "qualifierString": "name_of_column_from_bt",
              "fieldName": "if_i_want_rename",

               }],
```

fieldName is not required.
However to access your field value you will still have to use such SQL code:

```sql
SELECT
aAA.xxx.cell.value as xxx
FROM dev_test.telem_test
```

Answer (score 0):

"encoding": "string" ==> "encoding": "TEXT" or "encoding": "BINARY"

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#bigtableoptions

encoding

Optional. The encoding of the values when the type is not STRING. Acceptable encoding values are:
TEXT - indicates values are alphanumeric text strings.
BINARY - indicates values are encoded using HBase Bytes.toBytes family of functions. This can be overridden for a specific column by listing that column in 'columns' and specifying an encoding for it.